# Voting in the Council of Ministers

Tags: european-union

In the Council of Ministers, [qualified majority voting is used](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/council-eu/voting-system/qualified-majority/):

> When the Council votes on a proposal by the Commission or the High
>   Representative of the Union for Foreign Affairs and Security Policy...

And [unanimity is used](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/council-eu/voting-system/unanimity/):

> The Council has to vote unanimously on a number of matters which the
>   member states consider to be sensitive. For example:
>
> - common foreign and security policy (with the exception of certain
>     clearly defined cases which require qualified majority, e.g.
>     appointment of a special representative)

But the remit of the High Representative of the Union for Foreign Affairs and Security Policy is the common foreign and security policy.

So there appears to be a contradiction here. What am I missing?

Comment: It is not a contradiction because it is explicitly listed as an exception. Why it is an exception is probably a reasonable question.